# sprintf() precision .16 bug

Tags: c, string, printf, double

I have to do a project for university so I chose to code a calculator/equation parser.

Whole Program (without (syntax-)error handling):
[click here](http://ideone.com/xPomJk)

I have encountered a bug that occurs only when I set the precision in a sprintf()-call to 16. Everything works fine with any precision above or below and also 16 works fine in debug mode, too.

Expressions that cause my program to crash:

12/(-9)+3 , but 12/(-9) works fine

(1)+(2)+(3) and similar things

---

So here's what the code does:

-it looks for the "upper" parantheses pair in the user entered string

-> j: position of the first char inside the parantheses

-> i: position of the first char after the parantheses

-calculate the inside of the parantheses recursively with the same function until there is no more pair of parantheses

-another function is called to cast this calculation into double

-return value of function is recursive call of concatenation of string[0 to j-2]##result_str[j to i-2]##string[i to end]

---

Here's the code (important part I described above is all the way down at the end):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#define LENGTH(x)  (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))

int hasPar (char *); //Überprüft, ob Klammern im String sind und gibt Position der ersten Klammer zurück
char* subStr (char* , char* , int , int ); //Funktion, die Substring zurückgibt
double calcStr(char *); //Wertet Terme ohne Klammern aus
double calc (char *); //Rekursive Berechnung des Terms


int main(/*int argc, char *argv[]*/) {
    char *s/*, c*/;
    double ergebnis;

    do {
        puts("Taschenrechner. Ignoriert alles, au\xe1""er 0-9,.,+,-,*,/,^,(,)");

        fflush(stdin);
        s= calloc(100,1);
        scanf("%99[^\n]", s); //[^\n] bedeutet, dass alle Zeichen außer Zeilenumbruch eingelesen werden sollen

        printf("Erkannter Ausdruck:\n%s\n", s);

        ergebnis= calc(s);  
        printf("Berechnetes Ergebnis:\n%f\n", ergebnis);


        puts("Erfolg!");;
        free(s);
        fflush(stdin);
        //if (getc(stdin) == 'c') {break;}
    } while (0);

    return 0;
}




int hasPar (char *s) {
    for (unsigned int k=0; k<strlen(s); k++) { //k verwendet, da mit i Interferenzen mit calc() aufgetreten sind
        if ( s[k] == '(' ) {
            return k;
        }
    }

    return (-1);
}



char* subStr (char* dest, char* src, int offset, int len) {
    int input_len = strlen (src);

    if ( offset+len > input_len ) { //Wenn Substring größer sein sollte als Usprungsstring oder Substring Null Zeichen enthalten soll
        return NULL;
    } else if (len <= 0) {
        dest[0]= '\0';
    }

    strncpy(dest, src + offset, len); //len Zeichen werden aus s ab offset in t kopiert
    dest[len]= '\0';
    return dest;
}



double calcStr (char *s) {
    char *t, *t_first;
    int len_s= strlen(s), len_first=0;
    t= calloc(len_s, sizeof(char)); //Kopie von s zum Arbeiten erstellen, Schritt 1
    strcpy(t,s); //Kopie von s zum Arbeiten erstellen, Schritt 2

    //ACHTUNG: REIHENFOLGE WICHTIG FÜR KORREKTE ANWENDUNG VON RECHENREGELN

    if(t[0] != '+') { //+ als unärer Operator
        t_first= strtok(t,"+"); //String auf + prüfen, Nach Ausführung von strtok: t_first: String bis exklusiv +
        len_first=strlen(t_first); //Länge des Ergebnisstrings berechnen zum Vergleich mit Länge des Ursprungsstrings
        if (len_first != len_s) { //Wenn Länge gleich, dann ist hier auch der Inhalt gleich, also kein Plus enthalten
            switch ( t_first[len_first-1] ) { //Wenn + unär, also vor dem + ein anderes OpSym
                case '+':
                    t[len_first-1]= '\0';
                    return calcStr(t) + (calcStr(s+len_first));
                case '-':
                    t[len_first-1]= '\0';
                    return calcStr(t) - (calcStr(s+len_first));
                case '*':
                    t[len_first-1]= '\0';
                    return calcStr(t) * (calcStr(s+len_first));
                case '/':
                    t[len_first-1]= '\0';
                    return calcStr(t) / (calcStr(s+len_first));
                case '^':
                    t[len_first-1]= '\0';
                    return pow(calcStr(t), (calcStr(s+len_first)));
                default:
                    return calcStr(t_first) + (calcStr(s+len_first+1)); //Rekursives Aufrufen der Strings links und rechts des Operationszeichens
            }
        }
    }

    strcpy(t,s); //da t bei Überprüfung auf + verändert wurde, Wiederherstellung der Arbeitskopie aus Ursprungsstring
    if(t[0] != '-') { //- als unärer Operator
        t_first= strtok(t,"-"); //analog oben
        len_first=strlen(t_first); 
        if (len_first != len_s) {
            switch ( t_first[len_first-1] ) {
                case '+':
                    t[len_first-1]= '\0';
                    return calcStr(t) + (calcStr(s+len_first));
                case '-':
                    t[len_first-1]= '\0';
                    return calcStr(t) - (calcStr(s+len_first));
                case '*':
                    t[len_first-1]= '\0';
                    return calcStr(t) * (calcStr(s+len_first));
                case '/':
                    t[len_first-1]= '\0';
                    return calcStr(t) / (calcStr(s+len_first));
                case '^':
                    t[len_first-1]= '\0';
                    return pow(calcStr(t), (calcStr(s+len_first)));
                default:
                    return calcStr(t_first) + (calcStr(s+len_first+1)); //Rekursives Aufrufen der Strings links und rechts des Operationszeichens
            }
        }
    }

    strcpy(t,s);
    t_first= strtok(t,"*");
    len_first=strlen(t_first);
    if (len_first != len_s) {
        return calcStr(t_first) * (calcStr(s+len_first+1));
    }

    strcpy(t,s); //analog
    t_first= strtok(t,"/");
    len_first=strlen(t_first);
    if (len_first != len_s) {
        return calcStr(t_first) * (1 / calcStr(s+len_first+1));
    }

    strcpy(t,s);
    t_first= strtok(t,"^");
    len_first=strlen(t_first);
    if (len_first != len_s) {
        if (t_first[len_first-1]=='e') {
            if (t_first[0]=='-') {
                return (-1)*exp(calcStr(s+len_first+1));
            } else if (t_first[0]=='+') {
                return exp(calcStr(s+len_first+1));
            } else {
                return pow(calcStr(t_first), (calcStr(s+len_first+1)));
            }
        }
    }

    return atof(s); //String ist bei keinem Operationszeichen zerfallen => String ist Zahl ; atof castet string zu double (aus stdlib.h)

}


double calc (char *s) {
    double result_d=0.;
    char *t, *result_str;
    int check=1, i=hasPar(s), j=0;
    if ( i == (-1) ) {
        return calcStr(s);
    } else {
        j= ++i; //j=++i ist Position des Chars nach der ersten öffnenden Klammer
        while (check > 0) {
            if (s[i] == '(') {
                check++;
            } else if (s[i] == ')') {
                check--;
            }
            i++;
        }   //Bestimmen der Länge der "obersten" Klammer, i ist Position des ersten Zeichens nach der Klammer

        t= calloc (strlen(s), sizeof(char)); //string to store substring in
result_str= calloc (strlen(s), sizeof(char)); //string to store result of parantheses-calculation in
result_d= calc (subStr (result_str, s, j, i-j-1)); //call the function we're already in
sprintf (result_str, "%-.16f", result_d); //cast result back to string, this is where I think the crash is caused
return calc (strcat (subStr (t, s, 0, j-1), strcat (result_str, s+i))); //recursive call of concatenated string described as above
    }
}
```

-`subStr(char *dest, char *src, int offset, int len)` is just a function that uses `strncpy()` with error handling
`calc()` is the function we're in

-`s` is the *char given by the user

-`result_d` is calculated result of substring inside the parantheses (double-variable)

-`result_str` is the *char where the typecast of `result_d` is stored

---

I hope I didn't forget anything. If more code or info is needed just comment. I can also supply the *.exe to try out.

And remember: Everything works fine with `sprintf (result_str, "%.17f", result_d);` So I guess it can't be array out of bound (I think)

P.S.: if anyone has an idea of how to avoid the re-casting of a double to string, please say so.

Comment: Note: you don't need to use `sizeof(char)`, using `1` will do as `sizeof(char)` is by definition always 1.

Comment: Not enough code to guess what the problem might be, but note that when allocating strings you generally want `strlen(s) + 1` rather than `strlen(s)`, since you need an extra char for the terminator.

Comment: Please format your code properly. Make it more _human readable_. :-)

Comment: Are you sure that the buffer `result_str` is big enough ?

Comment: What is the value of `result_d`? You didn't specify it. Furthermore, you didn't specify what string `result_str` will get and what string do you think it should get.

Comment: We can't debug your English description of the code. And it might be your actual code has a bug that's not present in the description. So show the actual code.

Comment: This is the actual code. I just picked the lines I thought were important as everything else in this function is just to find the upper parantheses.

Where can I put a big amount of code other than here for you to look into it?

Comment: What does *'weird behaviour'* mean? BTW, you allocate `result_str` by the length of input `s`, but you don't necessarily know how long the input is! For example when you `sprintf` a value of `2` coming from the one-character string "2", it won't fit in 1- or 2-byte buffer. Make allocation size big enough to keep the `sprintf` result independent of `strlen(s)`,

Comment: @CiaPan weird behaviour just means it crashed. As described above.
And I tried to allocate huge amounts (300) for the strings but it didn't help either. And also it works with .17 so it can't be too small.

Comment: Well, you show us expressions that your code fails on, but don't show the whole code that parses these expressions. Given how loosely you use `strcat`, `strlen` and `malloc`, we can't have much confidence in the rest of your code. Also, your P.S. doesn't make sense without the code.

Comment: I am trying right now to get it to work in ideone.com. Will post here once it does.

Comment: Do you ever `free` the buffers you `calloc`-ed...?

Comment: @CiaPan: Yes I do where I can. But there I don't quite know how because the pointers are used in the return value. I just hoped it gets freed automatically after rising back to main... :-(
Also I added ideone link

Comment: You shouldn't need a large amount of code to demonstrate the problem.  You should reduce your code to the minimum necessary to show the problem and edit that into the question.  It should be a complete example anyone could copy/paste and compile/run themselves.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Ok, I reduced it down, but now there is no error handling anymore.

Comment: The code should be edited into the question, not an external link.  When you say `12/(-9)+3` breaks, does that mean your program crashes or it just gets the wrong answer?  If it is crashing then running it in a debugger would show you where and let you examine the call stack and state when the crash happens.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: In my post/question I said that it works fine in debug mode so I can't do as you described.
The program crashes. I edited my post.

Comment: You can debug a release version, you just need to make sure it has debug symbols available.  `-g` is the option to use if you're using gcc.  I assume you are because your program does not crash in a Visual Studio release build.  [gcc documentation on adding debug symbols](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options)

Comment: Ok, I checked and I confused it. I use the gcc4.8.1 release compiler with debug symbols always enabled. In Dev-C++ (which I use out of mobility reasons) you can choose to run without symbols which crashes. And with symbols it doesn't... 
To not further extend this conversation: My code works ok which is fine with me. I just wanted to "report a bug" that I can't explain for the hax0rs amongst you wanting to figure it out. I am not too interested in it, though.

Comment: Well, you're better off figuring it out rather than hoping it doesn't crop up again.  It's most likely not allocating enough memory for your strings and overflowing a buffer somewhere.  You could simply try doubling all the sizes and see if it still crashes without symbols, If not you can go back to the original allocations one at a time til you find the one that causes the crash.  *shrug*  Up to you.

Comment: You have many miscalculations of buffer sizes for allocated memory. If you want to use `strcpy`, you should allocate `strlen(s) + 1` to cater for the terminating null character. If you want to `strcat`, the bussfe must be able to hold both strings plus a terminator. If you want to print a float wth a precision of 16, you need 16 digits, plus one point, plus a possible exponent plus the terminator. Consider runnng your code with a memory checke, e.g. Valgrind, to fix the illegal memory accesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are `calloc`ing a lot of memory here and sometimes don't pay attention to the right dimensions. Also, if you allocate a string `s` on the stack, all early returns à la `return calc(s)` introduce a memory leak.

You use C99, so why not make use of variable-length arrays (VLAs)? The amounts you allocate are small and easily fit on the stack. You could even try not to allocate anything, but operate with begin and end pointers into the original (read-only) array. For reading input into a buffer, allocating a fixed size of memory has no advantage over using a local fixed-size buffer like `s[100]`.

Anyway, the main problem is your `calc`, where you construct a new string that has the part before the parens, the result of the sub-expression and the part after the parens. You use the same buffer for the sub-string that you pass to `calcStr` and for printing the result with a precision of 16. The former is okay, because you allocate the string length. The latter isn't okay, because the buffer may ne only be too short for printing a 16-digit number, but that buffer must also hold the result of the concatenation, i.e. the original string length minus the substring length plus around 20 chars for 16 digits plus point plus zero terminator.

Instead of concatenating, you could use a single `snprintf` expression. With the variable string precision format `%.*s`, you can write substrings.

Here's a better `calc` that guesses the dimension generously and takes care of not leaking the temporary buffer `t`:

```
double calc(char *s)
{
    double result_d;
    char *t;
    int check = 1;
    int i = hasPar(s);
    int j = 0;

    if (i == -1) return calcStr(s);

    j = ++i;
    while (check > 0) {
        if (s[i] == '(') {
            check++;
        } else if (s[i] == ')') {
            check--;
        }
        i++;
    }

    t = calloc(strlen(s) + 32, sizeof(*t));
    result_d = calc(subStr(t, s, j, i - j - 1));

    snprintf(t, strlen(s) + 32, "%.*s%.16f%s",
        j - 1, s, result_d, s + i);

    result_d = calc(t);    
    free(t);

    return result_d;
}
```

There is still one memory error in your code: You forgot to allocate memory for the null terminator for `t` in `calcStr` and you also leak that buffer. I suggest a VLA:

```
double calcStr(char *s)
{
    char *t_first;
    int len_s = strlen(s), len_first = 0;
    char t[len_s + 1]; //
    strcpy(t, s);

    ...
}
```

Lastly, the implementation of the calculator with string concatenation and substring evaluation is clumsy. 
Expressions are easily parsed with the [shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm), which will resolve operator precedence and parens easily.

Comment: Well thank you. This and your last comment above were the first helpful things here. I didn't come here without trying everything I could. 
I am now trying to understand the output of [Dr. Memory](http://drmemory.org/). And when I understand everything that you wrote I will accept the answer.
And thanks for the note about the algorithm. I did not know about it. (Mainly beacuse I did no research in advance because I wanted to do something on my own). The algorithm looks more like somthing done by a professional than my "puzzle"-implementation :-)And no one told me about VLAs...Again, thank you!

Comment: Ok I learned many things from your answer. That I didn't think of using snprintf for concatenating is a shame.
Unfortunately there is still an error in your rewritten code: it should be `result_d = calc(t)` or else you won't recognize any same-level parentheses.
BUT: I still don't know why the bug only occured in precision 16 and not above (I tried until 20 and all worked fine). Shouldn't it create the same leak/overflow?

Comment: Hmm. I could try to explain why it works for the shorter expression `12/(-9)`, but not for `12/(-9) + 3`. although you'd expect that it should be even worde for the short string, where you allocate less. In practice, the system doesn't allocate the exact amount of memory. It usually gives you memory in chunks of 2^n or 2^n minus some householding area, so both cases allocate, say, 16 chars. Replacing `(-9)` with a string of the order of 16 chars might just fit into the allocated memory for the first string, but not the second.

Comment: ... That might be true even if you write beyond the formally allocated memory. That still doesn't explain why the crash occurs with a precision of 16, but not with 17. After all, the allocation is the same, only the output might be longer. It's hard to find out without a debugger. It's also compiler and platform dependent. (That's the infamout "undefined behaviour" people keep talking about. In theory, anything can happen. In practice, there is usually a good explanation why things happen.)

Comment: ... Sorry about the `calc`/`calcStr` slip. I had only checked your (and simpler) input and focussed on the memory stuff. I understand that you want to do the project on your own - it makes you think abut the problem als also gives a sense of achievement. Your approach isn't all bad, either, it's just that strings are a pain to work with in C. (I once implemented an algorithm similar to yours in Pascal, but it has an additional step of tokenising, so that the array of chars was an array of tokens. That made it easier to identify parens and the dominant operators.)

Comment: Ok. I read about this way how memory is allocated before, but didn't think it can have such a big effect. I edited your post from `calcStr` to `calc`. Because there were less than 6 characters to change I shortended the word parentheses...

Comment: No sweat about the edits. The behaviour can be explained with the `malloc` implementation, but it shouldn't be of any concern to the programmer. Your problem was that you were invoking undefined hehaviour, because you wrote beyond the array and most examples just happened to work.